# How to remove embedded xlsx files from docx?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, embedding

I have a very big docx document(300mb). It is full of pictures, tables, spreadsheets, etc.

When I look at the document structure, I see that under **document.docx/word/embeddings/*** are all of the Excel sheets from where the tables and spreadsheets where copied! The compressed document is nearly 150MB!

The document is in a final state and the data and charts will not change any more.

Is it possible to remove all the embeddings and let Word save only the necessary values?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you share with us what you have already researched or attempted to resolve this and where you are stuck. There is a reasonable expectation here that you have at least tried something before asking for help.

Comment: @CharlieRB: This question might deserve a little slack.  To answer it properly requires an understanding of how Excel content is embedded, which isn't something a simple Google search would turn up.

Answer (score 2):

One way I found to strip out all of that stuff is to save the file as a PDF and then open the PDF file using Word. There is some chance the formatting won't be perfect, but, in my case, it removed embedded spreadsheets and retained perfect formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert your embedded content into something else (picture, plaint text, etc).

The official Microsoft solution is [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embedded-files-or-objects-found-ddba9b87-ab3a-4075-b2f7-fcbd309ef004?rs=en-US&ui=en-US&ad=US).

I found this site when I inspected (menu File / Check for Issues / Inspect Document) and found embedded content. Document inspector cannot remove automatically this kind of content without causing data loss.